# How do I sensibly rebase a very large out of date branch with master ? Can I rebase in "stages"?

Tags: git, merge, automated-tests, rebase, merge-conflict-resolution

**My problem:**

Hi,

I am working on a team with a large codebase with a large suite of automated tests. We have a branch called `big-breaking-change-branch` that touches loads of our codebase and has not been rebased with master in about 2 months. We want to rebase this with master and are having difficulty with it because it is so out of date.

Our repository currently looks like this:

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F master
     \
      \-> G big-breaking-change-branch
```

We want our repository to look like this:

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F master
                          \
                           \-> G big-breaking-change-branch
```

While `big-breaking-change-branch` branch has been worked on by one person other members of the team have been adding big features to `master` like `C`, `D`, `E`, `F`.

My problem is it is very difficult to test that the `C`, `D`, `E`, `F` features are working when I rebase the "normal" way. For example when I run this:

```
git checkout big-breaking-change-branch
git rebase origin/master
```

I get conflicts as expected, but even if I fix them I cannot run our testing suite to verify that `C`, `D`, `E` and `F` are working as the changes in `big-breaking-change-branch` are not compatible with the tests in `master` and we get loads of failures.

**My question**

Can I break up this rebase into stages so I can integrate the features `C`, `D`, `E` and `F` with `big-breaking-change-branch` one at a time?

**What I want to happen:**

Step 1:

Run some command that makes the repo look like this:

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F master
           \
            \-> G big-breaking-change-branch
```

Step 2: 
Integrate feature `C` with `big-breaking-change-branch`, fix any failures and verify it works by all the automated tests passing.

Step 3:
Run some command that makes the repo look like this:

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F master
               \
                \-> G big-breaking-change-branch
```

Step 4: 
Integrate feature `D` with `big-breaking-change-branch`, fix any failures and verify it works by all the automated tests passing.

...

ETC

**What I've tried:**

I've been experimenting with the --onto option for rebase but I am not sure it matches my use case.

Answer (score 0):

First thing: you are rebasing in the wrong direction. You checkout your branch and then run:

```
git rebase master
```

Either way, the answer to your question: sure.... you do:

```
git rebase C
# test... make sure it is ok. If things fail, you correct them (creating new revisions on top, I'd guess?)
git rebase D
# test
git rebase E
# and so on
```

This will be painful.... and you might have to correct more conflicts than when doing *git rebase master* in a single shot.... but it is what you want to do so,  go for it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a shot today and let you know

Comment: So I'm not sure this does what I want. If I do a `git rebase <target SHA>` to go to the target commit in a chain like this:

`Bob -> Bob -> Alice -> Bob -> Bob(target)`

Where Bob and Alice represent changes from differnt people in the master branch it turns out like this:

`Bob -> Bob -> Bob -> Bob(target)`

Alice's change seems to be gone if I do it like this. Do you know why this is?

Comment: Can you also elaborate please on what you mean by `rebasing in the wrong direction`? I have checked out `big-breaking-change-branch` and running `git rebase <master (or commit from master)>`

Comment: Hmm.... maybe I misread? I read that you check out master and then you rebase on your feature branch... and _that_ would be rebasing in the wrong direction. Never mind.